# chrome not saving httponly refresh token on incognito mode django react jwt auth

Tags: python, reactjs, django, jwt, refresh-token

I am building an app using django and react. Im using JWT auth, and access refresh tokens for auth. ive deployed it in heroku, connected my domain, now it works on regular browsing but on incognito it doesnt work, meaning when i log in the user, in incognito mode the refresh token doesnt get saved, so it cannot reauthenticate. ive read that its good to send the refresh token through httponly, so thats what im doing, but it deosnt get saved in the incognito but it does on regular. I tried to understand it using chatgpt but it says there isnt much i can do then swithcing to another auth method, but there should be a way, if httponly refresh token is the secure way of doing it there should be a way to make it work.

here is my website:http://www.chronocraftusa.com/
git:https://github.com/ashgharibyan/ChronoCraft

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
from environs import Env
import os

env = Env()
env.read_env()
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env.str("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool("DEBUG", default=False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['testserver', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'chronocraft-2bed77306ebc.herokuapp.com', 'chronocraft-backend-b55cb29d1834.herokuapp.com', 'chronocraft-frontend-4dd2abad499f.herokuapp.com', 'chronocraftusa.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #3rd Party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic", 
    #local
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'folders.apps.FoldersConfig',
    'lists.apps.ListsConfig',
    'tasks.apps.TasksConfig',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",  # new
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request', 
            ],
        },
    },
]


ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://chronocraft-frontend-4dd2abad499f.herokuapp.com/account/confirmed'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://chronocraft-frontend-4dd2abad499f.herokuapp.com/dashboard'
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:5173/account/confirmed'
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:5173/dashboard'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"
SENDGRID_API_KEY = env.str("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env.str("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = 'ChronoCraft.com - '

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": env.dj_db_url("DATABASE_URL")
}
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]  # new
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"  # new
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"  

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [  
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
    # 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    # 'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}


REST_AUTH = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.LoginSerializer',
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.TokenSerializer',
    'JWT_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.JWTSerializer',
    'JWT_SERIALIZER_WITH_EXPIRATION': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.JWTSerializerWithExpiration',
    'JWT_TOKEN_CLAIMS_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer', # custom user serializer
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.PasswordResetSerializer',
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.PasswordResetConfirmSerializer',
    'PASSWORD_CHANGE_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.PasswordChangeSerializer',

    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer', # custom register serializer
    # 'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.stration.serializers.RegisterSerializer',

    'REGISTER_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),

    'TOKEN_MODEL': None, # custom token model
    'TOKEN_CREATOR': 'dj_rest_auth.utils.default_create_token',

    'PASSWORD_RESET_USE_SITES_DOMAIN': False,
    'OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED': False,
    'LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE': False,
    'SESSION_LOGIN': True,
    'USE_JWT': True, # use JWT

    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': "refresh",
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',
    'JWT_AUTH_SECURE': True,  # Set to True for HTTPS
    'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE': 'None',  # Set to 'None' for cross-domain cookies
    'JWT_AUTH_RETURN_EXPIRATION': False,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_USE_CSRF': False,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_ENFORCE_CSRF_ON_UNAUTHENTICATED': False,
    # 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
    # 'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': "refresh",
    # 'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',
    # 'JWT_AUTH_SECURE': False,
    # 'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY': True,
    # 'JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE': 'Lax',
    # 'JWT_AUTH_RETURN_EXPIRATION': False,
    # 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_USE_CSRF': False,
    # 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_ENFORCE_CSRF_ON_UNAUTHENTICATED': False,
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:5173",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "https://chronocraft-frontend-4dd2abad499f.herokuapp.com",
    "http://www.chronocraftusa.com",
    'https://chronocraft-backend-b55cb29d1834.herokuapp.com'
]



# REMOVE THE COMMENT --------------------
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://chronocraft-frontend-4dd2abad499f.herokuapp.com", "http://www.chronocraftusa.com"]
# CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:5173"]


CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
# Change to false
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False 




SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": False,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": False,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",

    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE': True,  # Use Secure cookie for HTTPS
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE_SECURE': True,  # Use Secure cookie for HTTPS
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE_SAMESITE': 'None',  # Required for cross-domain cookies
}
```

login axios:

```
const loginAxios = () => {
        const csrfToken = getCookie("csrftoken");

        axios
            .post(
                "https://chronocraft-backend-b55cb29d1834.herokuapp.com/api/v1/accounts/dj-rest-auth/login/",
                loginInfo,
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
                    },
                }
            )
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("SUCCESSSS");
                // console.log(res.data);
                localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", res.data.access);
                axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
                    "JWT " + res.data.access;

                logIn();
                navigate("/dashboard");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("ERRORRRR");
                // console.log(err.response.data);
                axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = null;

                if (
                    err.response.data.non_field_errors &&
                    err.response.data.non_field_errors.length > 0
                ) {
                    setLoginErrors([
                        "Invalid username or password. Please try again!",
                    ]);
                    setLoginInfo(initialLoginInfo);
                }
            });
    };
```

example of other axios calls for getting models

```
export const listProjectsAxios = async (setProjects, navigate) => {
    const csrfToken = getCookie("csrftoken");

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(
            "https://chronocraft-backend-b55cb29d1834.herokuapp.com/api/v1/projects/",
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
                },
            }
        );
        // console.log("Successfully fetched projects data");
        // console.log(response.data);
        setProjects(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
            try {
                const refreshResponse = await axios.post(
                    "https://chronocraft-backend-b55cb29d1834.herokuapp.com/api/v1/accounts/dj-rest-auth/token/refresh/",
                    {},
                    {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {
                            "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
                        },
                    }
                );
                const newAccessToken = refreshResponse.data.access;
                localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", newAccessToken);
                axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
                    "Bearer " + newAccessToken;
                listProjectsAxios(setProjects, navigate); // retry fetching user data with the new token
            } catch (refreshErr) {
                console.error("Error refreshing token", refreshErr);
                navigate("/login");
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Error fetching projects list data", err);
        }
    }
};
```

Please someone explain.